# How can I test SAML RestAPI in Android?

Tags: java, android, saml

I tried this with openid-connect, and it is working. I want same thing for SAML. FYI, I'm doing demo with Keycloak. So I already changed protocol from openid-connet to SAML inside Keycloak console/dashboard.

Code:

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .build();
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            
            /*For openid-connect*/
            //RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "client_id=lifetrenz-client-1&username=test&password=test@123&grant_type=password&client_secret=c89b1eed-136d-445f-bfb0-e7e2bdac89ee");


            /*For SAML*/
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "client_id=lifetrenz-client-1&username=test&password=test@123&grant_type=password");


            /*URL is changing manually accoridng to protocol*/
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://10.0.2.2:8080/auth/realms/Lifetrenz/protocol/saml/token")
                    .method("POST", body)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            data = "CODE: " + response.code() + "\n" + "MESSAGE: " + response.message() + "\n" + "BODY: " + response.body().string();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please guide me. And please answer in Java instead of Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just change the protocol to SAML and then send OpenID Connect parameters.

Here's an example of a [SAML request](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_req.php). The parameters are completely different.

And you can't use REST API. SAML uses browser redirects.

Not a Keycloak expert but your application needs a [client-side SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the reply, because this is complicated and no one is replying, at least you did! So, I read both things. Now still problem persists. I'll clear one thing: I'm able to create user from Postman [Using openid-connect], see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64085441/which-credential-should-i-use-to-generate-token-followed-by-create-user-inside-k/64096024#64096024  | Now same thing I want to do in Android, but with SAML protocol, and what I tried code with SAML, that is already in question. | 2nd, In your suggested post there is not a single thing  related to Android.

Comment: It's okay if I need to open webview, I don't have problem.

Comment: You can check this example, in that they're using client provider login: https://github.com/learning-layers/android-openid-connect but they're doing with openid-connect instead  exactly same thing I want with SAML!

Comment: For Android you would use a js / node library.

Comment: You are creating a user by calling a REST API. OpenID Connect is designed to do this. SAML is not. You cannot call a REST API from SAML. For one thing, SAML uses an XML token and OpenID Connect requires a JWT token,

Comment: I'm not using js/node. 2nd, I'm okay with your suggestion, but where is the example? What I'll write code? that is no where! Can't you find, that I can follow?

Comment: What language are you using? If you click on the links in the client-side stack article I sent, you will see sample code and docs.

Comment: I want to do in Android (Java).